# How to disable gesture control in cvcalendar swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am using [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) to display calendar . I want to disable the swipe action in the calendar view. how it is possible?

Following code which calls cvcalendar and displays calendar. I had two buttons and nex and prev to change month view.

```
import UIKit

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!

@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!

@IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var eventTableView: UITableView!

var event : String = "1"
var shouldShowDaysOut = true
var animationFinished = true

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad() 
  monthLabel.text = CVDate(date: NSDate()).globalDescription

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
}

}
/*
* CVCalendar library functions to display calender and events
*/


extension CalendarViewController: CVCalendarViewDelegate , MenuViewDelegate {


func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
    return .MonthView
}

func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
    return .Sunday
}

func shouldShowWeekdaysOut() -> Bool {
    return false
}


func didSelectDayView(dayView: CVCalendarDayView) {
    let date = dayView.date

    if dayView.isCurrentDay {
    eventTableView.hidden = false
    eventTableView.reloadData()
    }

    else {

        eventTableView.hidden = true

    }
    println("\(calendarView.presentedDate.commonDescription) is selected!")

}

func presentedDateUpdated(date: CVDate) {
    if monthLabel.text != date.globalDescription && self.animationFinished {
        let updatedMonthLabel = UILabel()
        updatedMonthLabel.textColor = monthLabel.textColor
        updatedMonthLabel.font = monthLabel.font
        updatedMonthLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        updatedMonthLabel.text = date.globalDescription
        updatedMonthLabel.sizeToFit()
        updatedMonthLabel.alpha = 0
        updatedMonthLabel.center = self.monthLabel.center

        let offset = CGFloat(48)
        updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, offset)
        updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.1)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.animationFinished = false
            self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -offset)
            self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.1)
            self.monthLabel.alpha = 0

            updatedMonthLabel.alpha = 1
            updatedMonthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            }) { _ in

                self.animationFinished = true
                self.monthLabel.frame = updatedMonthLabel.frame
                self.monthLabel.text = updatedMonthLabel.text
                self.monthLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.monthLabel.alpha = 1
                updatedMonthLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        self.view.insertSubview(updatedMonthLabel, aboveSubview: self.monthLabel)
    }
}

func topMarker(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: CVCalendarDayView) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func dotMarker(shouldShowOnDayView dayView: CVCalendarDayView) -> Bool {
    let day = dayView.date.day

    if dayView.isCurrentDay{


        return true
    }


    return false
}

func dotMarker(colorOnDayView dayView: CVCalendarDayView) -> [UIColor] {
    let day = dayView.date.day
    let color = UIColor.greenColor()
    return [color]
}

func dotMarker(shouldMoveOnHighlightingOnDayView dayView: CVCalendarDayView) -> Bool {
    return false
}


}

// MARK: - CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate

extension CalendarViewController: CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate {
    func dayLabelPresentWeekdayInitallyBold() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

func spaceBetweenDayViews() -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}
}


    @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {

    calendarView.loadNextView()

}

@IBAction func previous(sender: AnyObject) {

    calendarView.loadPreviousView()
}
```

Comment: You want to disable functionality when user swipe for next month view?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yeah i just want to change month view on button click only

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable scrolling of `CVCalendarView` this way:

Go to `CVCalendarContentViewController.swift` then find the extension `CVCalendarContentViewController`.

In that extension change the size of `scrollView` by replacing this line:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width * 3, frame.size.height)
```

With this line of code:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
```

Hope it will help.

**UPDATE:**

Go to the project navigator the click on third icon which is Find Navigator as shown in below Image:

[image]

And search this line into that textField:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width * 3, frame.size.height)
```

And your result will be like this:

[image]

Click on that result and replace that line with this line:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
```